# Joint density function N

Tags: probability

[image]

I am trying to calculate the joint density function of a given functions shown below.

To simplify things i assume they are independent which is not given. Can anyone suggest me how to solve it without assuming dependency!

[image]

Comment: First of all what is the distribution of $Y$?

Comment: That is what is hard for me to understand. From the question Y is just define as a sequence of sum.

Comment: $X_i$ are Gaussian distributed, because they are jointly Gaussian distributed. Then fullstop. One needs to know if $X_i$ are independent or not.

Comment: joint density says that they are..

Answer (score 0):

1. This is the joint density function of $n$ independent standard
   normal random variables $X_i.$ Please make sure you understand
   why before continuing, because that insight may be a major
   point of asking the question.
2. Then, the sum of two normal distributions is another normal
   distribution. You add the two means and the two variances to
   get the mean and variance of the resulting random variable.
   What would be the *standard deviation* of the resulting random
   variable?  In your case, $Y_1$ is just standard normal, $Y_2 \sim N(0, 2).$
   [I am using notation in which the second argument is the variance,
   not the SD.]
3. Once you have the distributions of the $Y_i,$ for $i = 1, \dots, n,$
   reverse the idea I asked you to be sure to understand in step 1
   to find their joint distribution.

Comment: Thanks Bruce! For your detail explanation. I understand 1 and 2nd point. But not point 3

Comment: You are asked for the joint density function of the $Y_i.$ However, they are not independent, so you will have to find correlations and deal with the general formula for the multivariate normal. Compare the given joint density function with that. You are just posting pictures of exercises, not saying what you have tried, not giving context, so it is not easy to give advice, hints, etc. at the appropriate level.

Comment: I have added what i tried, but my work is with assumption of ndependecy!

Comment: Independence of the $Y_i$ is totally off the table. $Y_1 = X_1$ and $Y_2 = X_1 + X_2.$ To start, what is $Cov(X_1, X_1 + X_2)?$  Can you do it for $n = 3?$ What is the variance-covariance matrix of this tri-variate normal distribution?